# SQL queries to determine all values that would satisfy an arbitrary query

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to figure out how to efficiently run a set of queries that will provide a new table of all values that would return results for an arbitrary query.

Say my table has a schema like:

- id
- name
- age
- city

What is an efficient way to list all values that would return results for an arbitrary query (e.g., `SELECT * FROM main WHERE NOT city=X AND age BETWEEN Y AND Z`)?

My naive approach for this would be to use a script and recurse through all possible combinations of {city, age, age} and see which SELECTs return more than 0 results, but that seems incredibly inefficient. I've also tried building large joins on {city, age, age} as well and basically using that table as an argument list to the query, but that quickly becomes an impossibility for queries on many columns.

For simple conjunctive equality queries (e.g., `SELECT * FROM main WHERE name=X AND age=Y`), this is much simpler, as I can do something like:

```
SELECT name, age, count(*) AS count FROM main GROUP BY name, age HAVING count > 0
```

But I'm having difficulty coming up with a general approach for anything more complicated than that.

Any pointers in the right direction would be most helpful, thanks.

### EDIT:

It appears I did a very poor job explaining this, sorry.

Imagine a user gives me a database and a template query and says, "Tell me all the values I can use in this query that will yield results from this database." For example, the user might want to know all age range queries that will return at least one row (e.g., the template query is `SELECT * FROM main WHERE age BETWEEN X AND Y`).

In that particular example, one could run a SELECT to find the min/max ages in the database, and just tell the user to query between those ages.

Now imagine that the query template is more complicated, such as `SELECT * FROM main WHERE NOT city=W AND age BETWEEN X AND Y AND name LIKE Z`. How could one determine the range of W/X/Y/Z values that can be used with this query to return results? Does it require creating a join table with every single {city, age, age, name} combination and running the SELECT on each row? How can I do this efficiently so that the operation is time-bound on large databases?

Hopefully that clarifies it.

Comment: Maybe I am tired, but frankly I do not understand what you want.

Comment: lol sorry I am pretty tired too...the basic problem is: given a template query and an existing dataset, how can I determine all the values I can populate the query with that will return rows from the dataset? For the example I provided, what values of X, Y, and Z will return results from the dataset?

Comment: Still don't get it. Why is it a problem when you get no result?

Comment: lol in some shape or form yes, it was assigned to me. Anyway, just hoping for some pointers if anyone has ideas, or if anyone finds this problem interesting, I'm happy to brainstorm. My SQL isn't very good, so I'm guessing there's some syntactical magic I don't know about. Thanks.

Comment: If it helps, my current approach is to 1) build an indexed table grouped by all the variables of interest with counts, 2) determine all the unique values for each of the variables of interest, 3) use a script to recurse through combinations, populate the template query, and sum up matching counts from the indexed table. I figured this was at least faster than just running all the possible combinations on the table itself, but my approach is also proving to be painfully slow as mysql quickly becomes the bottleneck.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to write a trigger after insert into your table which inserts the values into another table if they don't exist already. This way you'd have a table with the distinct values of your table. This table would look something like

```
 columnNameFromYourTable  |  distinctValue
 city                        NY
 city                        LA
 age                         1
 age                         2
 ...
```

Then when you want to know if a record exists in your table for query `SELECT * FROM main WHERE NOT city=W AND age BETWEEN X AND Y AND name LIKE Z` you'd query the distinctTable with

```
select 1 from dual where 1=1
and not exists (select 1 from distinctTable where columnNameFromYourTable = 'city' and distinctValue = 'W')
and exists (select 1 from distinctTable where columnNameFromYourTable = 'age' and distinctValue BETWEEN X AND Y)
and exists (select 1 from distinctTable where columnNameFromYourTable = 'name' and distinctValue LIKE '%Z%')
```

This would be pretty fast then. If it returns `1` there is an entry in your table, if `NULL` not.

Comment: So I think the hard part is how to easily recurse through all possibly W/X/Y/Z values, and if there is a way to do so without any scripting. Doing this SELECT many times, especially if W/X/Y/Z have large cardinalities, seems prohibitively expensive. But I will try this and see if it's faster than my current approach. I'm thinking I might need to basically fetch count information in a script and recurse through all possible values in the script, and leave MySQL out of the picture...hoping there's a more sensible solution though.

Comment: @jasterm007: use the word 'iterate' rather than 'recurse'. You want to iterate through all the values - recursion is something completely different.